# The "save" method of model class works very long

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2, yii2-model

I have such method in controller, that simple sets value of `status` field to 0 or 1.

```
public function actionNews_status($id,$status){
    $status = ($status==1)?1:0;
    $number = false;
    $news = News::findOne($id);
    if(!is_null($news)){
        $news->status = $status;
        $number = $news->save();
        Redis::rset($CACHE_mat, null);
    }
    return json_encode(['status'=>$number]);
}
```

As it turned out, the method works for about 20 seconds.

I found out that line `$number = $news->save();` is working slowly.
I checked this with `exit` before and after this line.
I also found out that the `status` field itself is updated immediately, since the query to the table instantly shows the changes.
But the `save` method continues after that to work for a long time.

`status` field defined as TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0
and no have any indexes.

Maybe creation of index is to helps fix it?

MySQL database, InnoDB. In the table 78701 rows.

**Updated:**

I found out the following.
Slowly running the `afterSave` method call at the end of the `updateInternal`.
But before the line with this call, the script is executed quickly.
Slowly works a call the `afterSave` by itself, not a code inside `afterSave` method and not code before `afterSave` calling
Why this can happen?

Comment: mmmm... it's just a try, but does it change anything if you save passing false, like this $news->save(false)? Maybe your validation rules are so complex that the take a long time to execute...

Comment: @Masiorama No, it did not have any effect.

Comment: Are you sure is the save  method and not the cache reset ????

Comment: Yes, I commented a line with `Redis::rset` and it working the same long.

Comment: As far as I know the code is correct, so maybe you should debug in a more granular way to find out what's going on. xdebug can give you more details for sure.

Comment: I learned new details and added to the start question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Cause was found in overrided `afterSave` method in model class.